# Swift getting Images from Core data to Table View

Tags: ios, swift

I have an App their I receive some images from a Api (JSON).Im saving the url to the image into my core data as a string.
Now I have a TableViewController and I want to display these images as a subtitle on my tableviewcontroller next to a label.

How can I get these images ? I have a UIImage extension there I can download these images trough the url. But I dont know now how to get these into my tableview.

```
extension UIImageView {
    func downloadedFrom(url: URL, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
        contentMode = mode
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard
                let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
                let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
                let data = data, error == nil,
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                self.image = image
            }
            }.resume()
    }
   func downloadedFrom(link: String, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
        guard let url = URL(string: link) else { return }
        downloadedFrom(url: url, contentMode: mode)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableCellName
   cell.imageView?.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:"YourUrl"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
   return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before starting the answer, I hope you have a custom cell defined by inheriting from UITableViewCell which includes an UIImageView. If not, [you should do it first](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FtO5QT2D_H8).

[SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) is the most popular library for this kind of work. If you could use third-party library go ahead with it and use it. Here is a sample code for a Cell where you would display an ImageView over the network.

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! DeliveryCell

          //make url from the string by extrating the url from Core Data entity
           let imageUrl = URL(string: imageUrlString)!

          //set it on a UIImageView with SDWebImage
           cell.deliveryImageView.sd_setImage(with: imageUrl, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "profile"), options: .refreshCached, completed: nil)

           return cell
    }
```

I highly recommend this library because, if you try to do it manually using an extension, there are many possibilities you need to consider such as caching image, dynamical loading images in another thread, memory management etc. Everything is superbly handled in this library.

Here is a [tutorial which explains the process](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XPAaxF0rQy0) in detail.