# Problem with TableviewController/Rows/Images

Tags: ios, swift

Im Developing an App and I have some few problems with my tableviewcontroller.First of all, left to the picture there is free space.How can I get the Image bigger ? or how can I get this so that there is no free space. The image is a cell.imageview and its getting his image data from core data.
And the next problem is. I have some problems with the rows, you can see this on the picture.How can I fix this ?

[image]

Comment: You have to take UIImageView and label on cell and take outlet in table custom cell then assign image and text to custom imageview iand label

Comment: I think you should check out the answer in your previous question. You need custom UITableViewCell. Use auto layout and fix the UIImageView and UILabel as you want. check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52448081/348301

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you use the default `UITableViewCell` class , but you need to create a subclass of it and make every content custom

regrading label trimming you need to set `.numberOfLines` property of the UILabel item to `0` so it can wrap , a review for constraints may be like this

> ImageView : width , height (static/propertional) , top , leading
>
> label : leading to imageView , top - trailing and bottom to cell

This [Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights) may help you in creating the dynamic table cell

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it would be much more constructive for you to implement a subclass of `UITableViewCell` and specify any cell-related logic in there. An intuitive approach - based on the contents of your table view screenshot - would look something like this

```
class ShowTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    // MARK: - Outlets

    @IBOutlet weak var imgThumbnail: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblTitle: UILabel!



    // MARK: - Functions

    func setUp(withShow show: Show) {
        self.imgThumbnail.image = show.thumbnailImage
        self.lblTitle.text = show.title
    }

}
```

Note that the `setUp(withShow:)` function declared above is using a user-defined object of type `Show`

```
class Show {

    // MARK: - Properties

    var title: String?
    var thumbnailImage: UIImage?



    // MARK: - Initializers

    public init(withTitle title: String, andImage image: UIImage) {
        self.title = title
        self.thumbnailImage = image
    }

}
```

In my opinion, the latter approach conforms much better with Object Oriented Programming (OOP) standards. In case you need to add/remove any property to your `Show` object, it will be so much easier and cleaner to reflect those changes within your cells. All you would have to do is add/remove the respective `@IBOutlet` objects from your cell and configure them just as demonstrated in the `setUp(withShow:)` class function.

Moving on, you implement the following view controller that conforms to the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol, and populate your table accordingly

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Properties

    var shows = [
        Show(withTitle: "UFC 127: Penn vs. Fitch", andImage: RESPECTIVE_IMAGE),
        Show(withTitle: "Strangers in Good Company", andImage: RESPECTIVE_IMAGE),
        Show(withTitle: "Candles on Bay Street", andImage: RESPECTIVE_IMAGE),
        Show(withTitle: "Flight Angels", andImage: RESPECTIVE_IMAGE)
    ]



    // MARK: - View Life Cycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

}



// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource Extension

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return shows.count
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cellIdentifier = "showCell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ShowTableViewCell

        cell.setUp(withShow: shows[indexPath.row])

        return cell

    }

}
```

Note that you when declaring the `shows` array, you should replace the RESPECTIVE_IMAGE placeholder I have added with whatever image you want. You should also populate it with whatever static elements you want - or more dynamically - query them from your database.

Additionally, using auto-layout, you can manually determine the size of your image and, using the `Number of Lines` label attribute, you can prevent your labels from trimming.